# Can I create global variables that work accross routes in Sinatra (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm trying to make a ruby class manage most of what's going on in my application, and I intend to manage its params through the erb with embeded Ruby Code. I picture it goes something like this, but it's obviously not working:

```
    require 'sinatra'
    require './models/questionaire_manager'

    set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
    set :port, ENV['PORT']
    enable :sessions
    set :session_secret, 'SecretString#!$%'




    get '/' do
        @questionaire=Questionaire_Manager.new 0
        erb :index
    end

    post '/' do
        session[:number]=params[:number] 
        redirect '/quiz'
    end

    get '/quiz' do
        @questionaire.number=session[:number]
        @questionaire.genQuestionaire
        erb :quiz
    end

    post '/quiz' do
        redirect'/results'
    end

    get '/results' do
        @number=session[:number]
        erb :results
    end
```

I guess I should also say I can't get the hang of sessions and session params, and since Sinatra's page has been down for almost a week now, I really cannot check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this maybe?

```
require 'sinatra'
require './models/questionaire_manager'

set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :port, ENV['PORT']
enable :sessions
set :session_secret, 'SecretString#!$%'

helpers do
  def quiz_manager
    @questionaire = session[:quiz_manager] ||= Questionaire_Manager.new 0
  end
end

get '/' do
  # Uncomment the line below if you intend to create a new quiz each time
  # session[:quiz_manager] = nil
  quiz_manager   # Initializes the session variable
  erb :index
end

post '/' do
  quiz_manager.number = params[:number]
  redirect '/quiz'
end

get '/quiz' do
  quiz_manager.genQuestionaire
  erb :quiz
end

post '/quiz' do
  redirect '/results'
end

get '/results' do
  @number = quiz_manager.number
  erb :results
end
```

**Edit:**

To clarify what this is doing -- I've created a helper method called quiz_manager that initializes `session[:quiz_manager]` if it hasn't already been set - This will persist between routes. I'm also setting the class variable `@questionnaire` so that you can access it within your views.